# How to simulate device back btn press/ AppBar back press? WillPopScope is not called upon Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I was able to override the back button onPressed behavior using `WillPopScope`. Now, whenever I press the `device back button` or the `default AppBar back button`, the code inside `onWillPop` runs as expected.

The problem now is that I want to have my own custom buttons to navigate backward, but `Navigator.of(context).pop()` doesn't check the WillPopScope as if it doesn't exist.

- Is there a way to simulate the system's back behavior or call it somehow?
- I know I can just call the same function that is called by
  onWillPop() manually upon pressing my custom back button, but I was eager to find a cleaner method, as in the future I could easily forget doing that and cause bugs.

Comment: Could you share the code that you are trying? Maybe I can help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was to use `Navigator.of(context).maybePop()`instead. Or more specifically in my case, was to use `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator:true).maybePop()` as I was using nested Navigation.

Comment: This worked for me thanks, The Popscope widget handles it correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases, when you need to intercept the Android back-button, you usually add `WillPopScope` to your widget tree. However, when developing stateful widgets that interact with the back button, it's more convenient to use the `BackButtonInterceptor`.

For more details check this link: https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor

Answer (score 0):

While using StateFullWidget, It is more convenient to use `BackButtonInterceptor`.
Hope this will Helpful.
For more Details Please check this:
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor